# Where do you save a notepad file so python can open it in the program?

Tags: python, file

My program can't locate the file. How do I save the text file in the python directory on Windows? I've looked through other similar questions but cant find a basic guide to save into the same directory. Thanks for the help

```
user_input = input("file name")
fh=open(user_input,"r",encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: Don't you think it might be helpful to tell us the relevant directory structure and the code you're using?

Comment: I'm sorry i'm very new to programming. I would just like to open a txt file in my program.

Comment: fh=open(user_input,"r",encoding="utf-8")

Comment: Put relevant code into the question, not a comment.

Comment: user_input = input("file name")

Comment: This was a simple fix. All i had to do was save the text file in the same directory as my python file.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question right, all you have to do is search for the python directory, press the Windows key and type the name of a folder, and the folder will show up among the Start menu search results. Save the notepad file in that directory. Hopefully that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably giving relative paths to `user_input`. Relative paths are resolved based on the *current working directory* (cwd). cwd is the directory from which python was started, which can be anything (not only where it is located), depending on how you start the script.

To find out what the cwd is:

```
print(os.getcwd())
```

But instead of basing everything on CWD, I suggest you should do something else.

1st option: choose a different base directory:

```
base_directory = 'C:\\My Favourite Directory'
user_input = input("file name")
file_path = os.path.join(base_directory, user_input)
fh = open(file_path, "r", encoding="utf-8")
```

2nd option: specify absolute paths as input:

When asked, for file name, type:

> C:\My Favourite Directory\my file.txt